# Is there a way I can export multiple constants

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a a list of constants which I am exporting

```
export const ABC="abc"
export const DEF="def"
...
```

Is there a way I can export them in a single line .

I am aware of something like this

```
const ABC="abc"
const DEF="def"
...

export {ABC,DEF...}
```

but is there a way something like

```
export {
//define constants here
}
```

Comment: maybe `module.exports = {ABC: 'abc', DEF: 'def'}`, i never tried though

Comment: @boxdox - That's CJS. The above is ESM.

Comment: What's the thing about `export { /* define constants here */ }` that you like better than `export const ABC = "abc"; export const DEF = "def";`? To me those are basically the same. Is it the repeated `export`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder dang it i keep messing it up. yeah, i guess op wants to define constant inside the exports itself

Comment: Yes it would be great if I can export all at once instead of having a repeat export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to do one of the two things you listed (export them as you declare them, or use an export declaration gathering them together). (If it helps, it doesn't matter where the `export { ... }` is in relation to the constants; it can be above them if you prefer [yes, really]. Personally I like the inline `export` but it's a matter of style...)

You could export an object with properties, but then the whole object would be exported, and you couldn't pick out the properties on import (you'd have to destructure after importing).

Comment: FWIW, I go into the various `export` (and `import`) forms available in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Yeah , got it we can use object here then like ``` export const val = {ABC:"abc"....}```

Comment: @AkshaySharma - Right. Just beware that you **can't** then do `import { val: { ABC } } from "x";` or similar, `import` doesn't do nesting or destructuring. You'd need to do `import { val } from "x"; const { ABC } = val;`. Also beware that `ABC` is no longer constant (but you can fix that with [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)).

Answer (score 3):

You can declare multiple constants in the same line. Clever use of spacing gives you this:

```js
// a.js
export const
  ABC = "abc",
  DEF = "def",
  GHI = "ghi";

//b.js

import { ABC, DEF, HGI } from './a.js';
```

Note the comma between lines and the semicolon in the last one.

Prettier would like to have a chat with you though.